# Displaying logarithmic Gantt or Minute-long tasks for event coordination

Tags: pm-software, gantt

**Is there a way to show minute-long tasks for event choreography on a Gantt chart?**

*ProjectLibre* is my preferred Gantt tool, and I've not discovered a way to change the display to minutes, but tasks appear with the smallest measurement of "hours".

**Alternative #1** is to create 2 Gantt displays, one to show the complete timeframe (planning, practice & publicity), and the other which isolates the event (e.g. performance of school play).

**Alternative #2** would be something like a logarithmic Gantt, compressing the far distant items, and expanding the critical hour at the end. Think of a wedding...planned for months, and focused on the day, or even hour (ceremony & reception).

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the product you use.

The [ProjectLibre blog](https://www.projectlibre.com/blog/timeline-minuteshours) says it's not possible in ProjectLibre:

> In the Task View you can zoom into an hourly format.  It is actually 2-hour increments.  Project Management to the hourly level in tasks is pretty granular.

OTOH in [MS Project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-a-task-duration-0c551218-e543-4a5a-80f5-363c5c7c4e49) you can choose between minutes (m), hours (h), days (d), weeks (w), or months (mo).